# Unable to locate DeviceSupport directory with suffix 'DeveloperDiskImage.dmg'

Tags: xcode

I am writing this to provide a solution for others in the future.

This error occurs when you have an older version of Xcode installed on your computer and you are trying to run the app on a newer version of iOS.

- You will need to download the latest stable version of Xcode and its corresponding "Command Line Tools" [here.](https://developer.apple.com/download/all/)
- If you don't want to update your version of Xcode, but still want to use the latest IOS simulators (Iphone 14 etc) follow the below steps:

1. Download the IOS version you want from [this repository](https://github.com/filsv/iOSDeviceSupport)
2. Go to your `Applications` folder, right click on `Xcode` and click `Show Package Contents` and navigate to `Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport` and drag and drop the file you downloaded from the repository into this directory.
3. Restart Xcode and start using the device.

Answer (score 4):

**tl;dr** If you're developing a Flutter app and you're encountering this error, you should upgrade to Flutter version 3.13.0 or higher.

--

I've recently encountered this error when upgrading to Xcode 15. For me, it occurred because I was attempting to run my Flutter app on an iOS 17.0 device using an older version of Flutter (3.10.6-stable).

From Xcode 15 / iOS 17.0 and onwards, Apple has changed the way that DeviceSupport works and so the Flutter team have also had to modify their code to accommodate the change.

More can be read here:

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/730947

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/128531